# QuickBlox iOS SDK Update Message

Tags: quickblox

How to update sent message in QuickBlox iOS SDK?
I'm using QuickBlox 2.17.1. 
There is no such method as `updateMessage` in `QBRequest`.
I would like to update text and custom parameters of message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API method to [update a message](https://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Update_message).

Note, that it is only possible to update following parameters: `read`, `delivered`, `message`.

In SDK, there is no updateMessage method, but there are methods for updating `read` and `delivered` fields, such as `markMessagesAsRead`, `markMessagesAsDelivered`.

Custom parameters cannot be updated neither by API nor SDK methods.